Metamask loading forever firefox
Metamask is up to date, i try unpin and pin it again, clear all caches and cookis, problem still there. Problem is that i don't have all priv. key of all the addresses :(. I m using Macbook pro.
If any solution for this thanks in advance!


I'd suggest to try with another browser. If the problem persist you should report the issue to the creators.
